# Silverlight 4 and silverlight enabled WCF WebService - Cannot get it to work

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight, wcf

I have been struggling with this all day (and yesterday as well).
Basically, I have an ASP.Net website, consisting of a single page.
The page has a Silverlight APP, that lets your draw/write a signature. The Silverlight app saves the signature as an image, and sends it to a webservice, that is supposed to save it in the database.
ALL of this is in the same VS2010 solution.

But no matter what I try, I cannot get the Silverlight/webservice interaction to work.
My completed event doesn't fire and it looks like the method I am calling doesn't fire either.
I'm not sure how I can debug the webservice, to see if the method actually gets called.

So some code, would probably help, even though it is so simple.

```
void CallService()
{
    ImgService.ImageServiceClient MyClient = new ImageServiceClient();
    MyClient.HelloWorldCompleted += new EventHandler<HelloWorldCompletedEventArgs>(MyClient_HelloWorldCompleted);

    MessageBox.Show("Starting deposit");
    MyClient.HelloWorldAsync();
}

void MyClient_HelloWorldCompleted(object sender, HelloWorldCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("End of hello world\n" + e.Error.ToString());
}
```

Help me Stackoverflow, you're my only hope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To debug web service you only have to set a breakpoint in your webservice method and start it in debug mode.

Then update your client webreference to the debugging web service (take a look at its port).

Comment: Alright, doing this it does go through the method, in the service. Still, i get no completed event :(

Comment: It should throw an exception server or client side, it can't be waiting forever :-S

Comment: It's not waiting. I don't see anything happening. The Silverlight app reloads, and that is it. Actually, maybe that is the problem? I call the CallService method from a javascript on my asp.net page.

Comment: I believe this is the cause. I have made a quick attempt, to call the function from my silverlight code, instead of a javascript on the hosting page, and the event triggers. I guess the page's postback fired before the silverlight event.

Comment: Oh I didn't know the whole scenario. I'm not sure of when it's gonna be fired 8-)